# Installing bpython on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10, 64-bit, bpython

I am attempting to install bpython on Windows 10 and have followed the process to the best of my ability as outlined on the [official bpython website](https://docs.bpython-interpreter.org/windows.html) and on this [helpful GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/heitorlessa/20bb6b6826878f01b0c5cbb1e6bf0982).

I am running PowerShell on a 64bit laptop running Windows 10, and so I downloaded the python 3.7 release for Windows AMD 64-bit from the [release page](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#curses) which is `curses-2.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`.

I already successfully installed bpython via pip, so when I downloaded this wheel file I attempted to install it and got this error:

[image: this error]

After this, I downloaded the win32 version `curses‑2.2‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl` and ran it just for kicks and it outputs this:

[image: output this]

and also was able to run the program successfully one time until I hit the return key while creating a basic hello world function and it output this error:

[image: this error]

It now outputs this error any time I attempt to run bpython.

I have both python 2.7 and 3.7 installed on my computer, so I would like to install bpython for both, but need to at least get it to work for one first.

Did I perform the installation incorrectly or is there some other issue or step that I missed?

Answer (score 3):

BTW, instead of downloading `curses‑2.2‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl` you can:

```
pip install windows-curses
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64714934/11323942).

Comment: windows-curses works great, but one more little fix required.  see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75340151/912236

Answer (score 2):

The last error happens because *bpython* fails to write the history file. I just set the history length to zero, read details [here](https://docs.bpython-interpreter.org/configuration.html#hist-length).

Here's one-line solution (warning: overwrites *bpython* config if you wrote any):

```
Set-Content -Path "$env:userprofile\.config\bpython\config" -Value "[general]`nhist_length=0"
```

On Windows you have to use `bpython-curses.exe` or `python -m bpython.cli`, not just `bpython` command.