# Can't install bpython on Windows 10 via pip

Tags: windows-10, bpython

I've tried to setup `windwos-curses` as first step and it completes fine.

```
python -m pip install windows-curses
```

Also the following

```
python -m pip install bpython
```

does not show any problems.

Unfortunately running `bpython` results in a

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'
```

Does it mean that `bpython` is not running on Windows 10 or is there another option for the installation here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution on their [github](https://github.com/bpython/bpython/issues/649).

> According to #509 Blessings doesn't work on Windows even with the custom curses library. We ought to update the Windows install instructions in the readme and on the site to say that bpython-curses needs to be run instead of bpython. We should also consider making bpython-curses the default on Windows

So, I'm running `bpython-curses` and it looks good to me (a few commands are [not available](https://github.com/bpython/bpython/issues/736) though).

> Unfortunately, there was a bug, namely [it deletes the current line and returns back at the start of the history](https://github.com/bpython/bpython/issues/859), when I type an underscore or a capital `P`, but [it has been fixed now](https://github.com/bpython/bpython/commit/e66dc0ac766ad38bba41dea9a1612dcda2b2fb5e) by Sebastian Ramacher.

Notice also that their home [suggests](https://docs.bpython-interpreter.org/en/latest/windows.html) to install an unofficial windows binary for pdcurses, but either way it confirms that you have to launch it *by typing* `bpython-curses` *on your prompt*.

Comment: This no longer works, but there's an easy fix, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75340151/912236